# Bash two text files comparision script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, script

Given two files, I want to write a shell script that reads each line from file1 and checks if it is there in file2. If a line is not found in file2 it should keep it lets say in a table TAB1. Also, if there any any additional lines in file2, which are not in file 2 it should keep it lets say in a table TAB2.

The files can contain words numbers or anything. For example :

file1 :

```
Hi!
1234
5678
1111
hello
```

file2:

```
1111
5678
1234
Hi!
hellothere
```

In this case there should be "hello" in TAB1, and "hellothere" in TAB2

If two files are equal I want to return with "files are equal" echo or something like that.

How can I do this? I've tried experimenting with diff, but without success.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to sort each file. Then you need to use `comm`. Finally you can extract the columns that `comm` produces using `awk`. So something like this.

```
#! /bin/bash
sort $1 > $1.sorted
sort $2 > $2.sorted
comm -3 $1.sorted $2.sorted > columns
if [ -s columns ]; then
  TAB1="$(awk '{ print $1 }' < columns)"
  TAB2="$(awk '{ print $2 }' < columns)"
  # do something with TAB1 and TAB2
else
  echo $1 and $2 contain the same data
fi
```

You would call this script like this:

```
./myscript file1 file2
```

after making the script executable with `chmod`.

Comment: oh, that is nice. Any easy way to get those columns into variables/table? I need to perform extra operations on them before printing output

Comment: @SSV OK I updated it

Comment: well, everything is saved in TAB1 this way.

TAB2 is empty (one TAB should contain additional entries, second missing entries).

Comment: Partialy solved it by running comm twice - once with -13, and later with -23